# porque el body no toma toda la pantalla

Tags: css, css3

hola tengo este código bastante sencillo un dos div dentro de otro div con flexbox dentro del body pero no entiendo porque el body no toma el 100% del alto de pantalla que hago mal? el widht cambia conforme a la pantalla pero el height se queda en 400px

```
*{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        
    }
    body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        
    }  
    .divflex{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    
    }
    .container{
        align-items: center;
        border: 2px solid red;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        
    }
    .cuadro{
        border: 2px solid green;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

y este es el html:

```
<body>
<div class="divflex">
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="cuadro" id="cuadro"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="cuadro" id="cuadro"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si usas el mismo codigo y le **cierras la etiqueta "body "**funciona normal si le pones un backgroud al body lo veras.
No es necesario pero si depronto te preguntas como usar un div del alto de pantalla existe el estilo    **height: 100vh;**

Comment: muchas gracias, no me di cuenta de ese detalle.. esta bien que ponga el width con 100% o es irreleavante?

Comment: Pues eso siempre depende de la necesidad ,yo normal mente no modifico el body de alto y ancho sino su contenido

Answer (score 0):

para resolver realice lo siguiente que encontre en un foro

```css
html, body{
height: 100%;
}
```